# Sending mass emails to OpportunityContactRoles' Contacts

Tags: email, contact, massemailmessage

I would like to send mass emails to some of my clients in Salesforce, particularily only the contacts that are related to Opportunities that match a certain criteria.

I have a custom number field in my Opportunities, only opportunities where this number is > 0, the opportunity itself can sometimes have more than one contact so it must be able to send emails to all contacts listed within that Opportunity.

Can this be done, and if so how? I have attempted the Mass Email function with and filtering contacts, but it only allows you to filter by Contact object.

Comment: Are the contacts related to the Account or are they also Partners and other Users, etc? How to search for them would depend on your answer. Also, do you have any custom fields in Opportunity that hold the ID's of these related contacts and/or Users? Anything you can tell us to clarify their relationships to Opportunity, Accounts, Contacts and Users would be helpful in providing you guidance. If there's something that connects them with Opportunity as the WhatID that would be the optimal way to find them.

Comment: So Opportunities have Contact Roles (related list) attached to them, I would like to email these people or atleast the Primary contact. The contact is usually a child of the Client (which the Opportunity is attached to)

Comment: Understand that the contact for the Account is a child of Account. Are your "clients" Accounts or are they Partners and do you want to also email everyone that has a Contact Role (including Users)? If so, you'll need to query based on the WhatID (the Opp ID) to get them into a list for each OppID. Otherwise, will probably want to approach it from the Account side of Opportunity. Do you want to run a report to get your list or do you want to query for it? Either way will need a list of Opps to start with and work back from there.

Answer (score 1):

The object is OpportunityContactRoles and is a junction object between opportunity and contacts. This is not currently possible with workflow.

An idea has been opened (6 years ago):
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrHdAAK